# how to use arrays in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

How would you write a VBA function that:

- takes an array, an optional minimum and an optional maximum
- returns an array with each value less than the minimum replaced by the minimum value, and each value higher than the maximum replaced by the maximum value?

And how could I test the function by

1. calling it from an array formula on a sheet and
2. by writing to a range from a VBA array?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a proof of concept function than a practical one. You need to use type Variant for the optional parameters if you don't want to set a default value and instead us the "IsMissing" function.

It takes an excel range, like A1:A5, or A1:B5, and 2 optional paramters (min and max). It'll spit out a string telling you the new values of the range.

As a test, put values 1,2,3,4,5 in A1 through A5. Now, in B1, write this:

```
=CheckArray(A1:A5,3)
```

You should get back the result "The range is now: 3, 3, 3, 4, 5" since you did not give a max.
You can also do:

```
=CheckArray(A1:A5,,3)
```

And that will return "The range is now: 1, 2, 3, 3, 3"

```
Function CheckArray(ByVal cell_range As range, _
                    Optional ByVal min_value As Variant, _
                    Optional ByVal max_value As Variant)

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim test As String
vArray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        'Check the min. value
        If IsMissing(min_value) = False Then
            If vArray(i, j) < min_value Then
                vArray(i, j) = min_value
            End If
        End If
        'Check the max value
        If IsMissing(max_value) = False Then
            If vArray(i, j) > max_value Then
                vArray(i, j) = max_value
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
' The function is done. The below is just to spit out a test result.
For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        test = test & (", " & vArray(i, j))
    Next
Next

CheckArray = "The range is now: " & vbLf & Right(test, Len(test) - 2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to test your vba, you could create a procedure with a **hard-coded array**.

If it is a user-defined function, you can call it **with a range as an argument**, but you will probably have to set breakpoints because UDF do not display errors as classical vba does.

Comment: I wrote a quirky way to do it above in my answer that spits out the array as a string, but I also prefer using breakpoints to test UDFs as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you would need an array for that, and you can do that without VBA !
Say your MIN is 3 and your MAX is 16, then `=MAX(MIN(D6;16);3)` will do the trick.
And, if you really want to, you can still enter that as an array formula.